# How to set username and password in axios get method header

Tags: javascript, reactjs, httprequest, axios, ajax-request

I want to fetch some data from a server via axios in my react project. When i put the url on browser and hit enter browser ask me username and password and after that, i can see the json data. But i dont know how to set the password and username in axios header in a get method. I have searched it in many forums and pages,especially this link didin't help me: [Sending axios get request with authorization header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45316243/sending-axios-get-request-with-authorization-header) . So finally i tried (many things before this, but i was more confused):

```
componentDidMount() {
   axios.get('http://my_url/api/stb', {auth: {
    username: 'usrnm',
    password: 'pswrd'
}})
   .then(function(response) {
       console.log(response.data);
       console.log(response.headers['Authorization']);
   }).catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

And i can not get anything. I get this error in console:

```
Error: Network Error
Stack trace:
createError@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:2195:15
handleError@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:1724:14
```

Actually, the api documentation mentioned that with these words:

> If there is no header or not correct data - server's answer will
>   contain HTTP status 401 Unauthorized and message:

```
< {"status":"ERROR","results":"","error":"401 Unauthorized request"}
```

> For successful authentification is sufficient to add in every request
>   header to the API:

```
Authorization: Basic <base64encode("login":"password")>
```

The weird thing is, when i use postman, the response send me a "401 unauthorized" response below the body section. But i can not see any 401 errors in browser's console.

Comment: I think url is password protected not the api, please confirm that, or pllease share the url for api

Comment: sorry i cant share the url and yes, url is protected and as i mentioned above, it says that we must set an Authorization in get method's header.

Comment: then first you have to login , login will be accessible without headers , that wil return token , via this token we'll be able to access other apis

Comment: CORS error maybe? check the network tab in console

Comment: you can try something like so `axios.get('http://usrnm:pswrd@my_url/api/stb')`

Comment: vivek,i authenticated on browser but still same error...

Comment: @UXDart yes i had cors error in chrome but there was no cors error on firefox but now, i have cors error all browsers. And so is the way that i made is true above?

Comment: @Amr Aly i tried bot doesnt work

Comment: the auth in axios is ok... but you will need to enable CORS in your server

Comment: how can i do that?

Comment: and what does that mean: uthorization: Basic <base64encode("login":"password")>.. i think i have two problems, one of them is cors, the other is: i cant do authorization right

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok i found the solution. As i mentioned in the comments that i wrote for my question, there was a cors problem also. And i figured out that cors problem was appearing because of that i can not authorize correctly. So cors is a nature result of my question. Whatever.. I want to share my solution and i hope it helps another people because i couldent find a clear authorization example with react and axios.

I installed base-64 library via npm and:

```
componentDidMount() {
        const tok = 'my_username:my_password';
        const hash = Base64.encode(tok);
        const Basic = 'Basic ' + hash;
       axios.get('http://my_url/api/stb', {headers : { 'Authorization' : Basic }})
       .then(function(response) {
           console.log(response.data);
           console.log(response.headers['Authorization']);
       }).catch(err => console.log(err));
    }
```

And dont forget to get Authorization in single quotes and dont struggle for hours like me :)

Comment: Anyway, you can use `btoa(tok)` without installing base-64 library also :D

Comment: For a React-Python3Flask-Nginx-AWS build the flask_cors library works with this answer without changing any additional moving parts (ie nginx) as of Feb 2019.

Comment: @l2aelba solution works if you are working through the CLI, but I see you're working in React so instead use `Buffer.from(tok).toString('base64')` if you don't want to install an extra package.